# Embedding a php function within a php form template variable

Tags: php, html, templates

I'm trying to use a php function within a template html form that is being assigned as a php variable. I know that I can use standard $ variables and they will display ok, but I don't know how to use a function.

Essentially, I have a database with a set of values that I want to use to populate a drop down select form. I need to display the form in a couple of places so it makes sense to template the form with a variable.

So far I have the following PHP. Any help would be gratefully received! The array works fine - but displaying it within the form I'm struggling with.

> ```
> $query = "SELECT 
>   property.propertyid,
>   property.reference,
>   property.userid, 
>   users.userid,
>   users.username
> FROM 
>   property
>     LEFT JOIN users ON property.userid = users.userid
> WHERE 
>   property.userid = ".$varuserid."
>   ";
>
> $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
> $listarr=array();  
> while($qy = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
> $listarr[] = "<option value=\"".$qy['propertyid']."\">".$qy['reference']."</option>";
> }
>
> $form = <<<HTML
> <form name="insert" method="post" action="?page=account&amp;a=insert&amp;form=1">
>   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
>     <tr> 
>       <td width="24%" align="left" valign="top">Property ID</td>
>       <td width="76%">      
>         <select name="propertyid" size="1">
>
> foreach($listarr as $key => $value) { echo $value }
>
>         </select>
>       </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr> 
>       <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
>       <td>
>       <input name="userid" type="hidden" id="userid" value=$varuserid />
>       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert transaction!" /></td>
>     </tr>
>   </table>
> </form>
> HTML;
> ```

Thanks,
Simeon`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a loop inside a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) but you can use variables.

As you already have your list, what you can do is:

```
while($qy = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $listarr[] = "<option value=\"".$qy['propertyid']."\">".$qy['reference']."</option>";
}
$list = implode(" ", $listarr);
```

And in your heredoc:

```
<select name="propertyid" size="1">
    {$list}
</select>
```

**Edit:** Note that you need to do that for all variables you include in the heredoc, so:

```
<input name="userid" type="hidden" id="userid" value={$varuserid} />
                                                     ^          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tend to do:

```
<select name="propertyid" size="1">    
<?php foreach($listarr as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option> 
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

That way you can still see the format on the page :)

Comment: Thanks - I think I tried something like this but got a bit stuck and couldn't make it work - Partly because I've got 2 different variables in the array - one is a reference and the other is the id.